# Select array sub-sample that optimizes a function

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have an array of `N` elements and a function `func()` that takes as input `M` *unique* elements from the array, with `M<N`. I need to find the subset `M*` that maximizes my `func()`.

I can't use an exhaustive search (ie: test every possible subset `M` that can be created from the `N` elements in the array) because the total number of combinations is too large even for modest values of `N, M`.

I can't use any of the [usual scipy optimization algorithms](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) (at least none that I am aware of) since I'm not working with a continuous, or even a discrete, parameter; rather I'm trying to find a *subset of elements* that maximizes my function.

Is there some Python algorithm in any package that could help me with this?

Comment: You will have to spell out the problem / specify `func` to get any productive answers. So far, all you have told us: the problem is discrete (i.e. no gradient descent possible), and brute-forcing is prohibitively expensive because of the combinatorial nature of the problem.

Comment: I haven't been more specific about `func()` because I'm after a general solution that is able to work on basically any `func()` that I create.

Comment: Let me know if you do get a solution. There are a lot of people in combinatorics that have a bunch of problems that they would like solutions for. ;-) All jokes aside, consider that `func` could be the traveling salesman problem or any other (potentially or actually) N=NP problem. That immediately tells you that such a general recipe doesn't exist (yet -- as I said, let me know if you find a solution).

Comment: Thanks Paul, I do realize that this is a hard problem to resolve. I was thinking maybe doing a genetic-algorithm like approach where I start with a generation of random samples of `M` length, and then combine the "best" solutions found with some strategy. I'll post here if I find something that more or less works.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Today seems to be that kind of Friday, though. I had more brain farts today than I care to count.

Comment: One last thing: for a genetic algorithm to work at all (better than random sampling), you do need to have some sort of continuity in your cost function: for example, the `func({1,2,3,4,5})` needs to be close to `func({1,2,3,4,42})`. If that holds then there may be other, faster approaches that work well (some greedy optimization methods might apply).

Comment: That is definitely true in my case, which is why I thought of using a genetic algorithm. I'll look into greedy optimization methods. Thank you Paul!